# How can I make the column numbers change to start at zero again in a pandas data frame that has been sorted

Tags: python, pandas

When I sort a data frame in pandas the row numbers are that were 0,1,2,3 are now 0,2,4,3. How can I keep the data sorted and create new row numbers?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide a [mcve] including sample input and expected output, as well as code for what you've already tried based on your own research

Comment: Do you mean row (index) numbers? If so, ```df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)```

Comment: Yes, this worked Nicko thank you. Sorry, I meant rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned in the comment that you are looking for row numbers, I'm just getting an official answer listed.

To reset the row (index) numbers, use:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```